# Start node app with non root user | Permission denied

Tags: server, permissions, sudo, users

I have an ubuntu (v19) server, which I use to host a node web app. Usually I was loged in as root and was able to start the app with `node index.js` or s`udo node index.js`.

Ubuntu Info:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.10
Release:        19.10
Codename:       eoan
```

I red that starting my node app with the root user is bad, because it can lead to security issues.

I created a new user:

```
adduser example_user
```

I logged in with the new user, but I can not start the app with `node index.js`.

It gives `Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:443`.

As far as I understand adding the new user to the sudo group will give him sudo rights and then it misses the whole point, then the new user would be equal to root, or am I wrong?

I must be able to start the app with `node index.js` NOT `sudo node index.js`.

I tried moving the whole project into the homefolder of the new user and install it again with npm install, but I do not have permissions to do this aswell.

I understand that I need somewhere to give the new user permissions, but I have no clue how. There are so many informations on the web, but I am a bit worried to try everything out, because I could mess things up.

**EDIT**

So far I think that new users, which do not have root rights cannot use ports <1024, so I need a way to allow the new user to use port 443 for SSL.

Comment: @guiverc I think it must be an ubuntu permission issue with the new user. I thought it belongs here. I will search help somewhere else if I am wrong here. I try to add more relevant information now.

Comment: @guiverc I edited the question.